# How do tailless aircraft yaw?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, tail

I was doing research on control surfaces present on an aircraft and I noticed that some aircraft like the B2 Spirit does not have a vertical tail stabilizer and therefore no rudder either.

[image: Northrup Grumman B-2 Spirit]

How do aircraft such as these perform turns and counteract adverse yaw in banked curves? Do they apply some sort of differential thrust system for turning?

Comment: This answers you question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2252/42636

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Technically the B-2 bomber has rudders, they are "drag rudders" (or split rudder) and are located on the outer portion of the wing:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-B-2-bomber-achieve-yaw-stability-and-yaw-control-without-a-tail)</sup>

The rudders open in a clamshell configuration to create a drag force on the outer part of the wing. Because these are on the outer part of the wing, they can create a significant yaw force.