# How the German Horten Ho 229 flying wing can cancel the adverse yaw in turning?

Tags: aircraft-design, flying-wing, adverse-yaw

How the German Horten Ho 229 flying wing type of aircraft-design, cancel the adverse yaw effect in oblique/  diagonally turns?How the pulley on the controls could mix up to do the dual role (bank and yaw inside the turn to cancel asymmetrical lift)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a flying wing keep from going into a flat spin when maneuvering?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/how-does-a-flying-wing-keep-from-going-into-a-flat-spin-when-maneuvering) → "The Hortens used speed brakes near the wingtips"

Comment: The Ho229 does not have splitting ailerons.

Comment: speed brakes ≠ "splitting ailerons"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horten Ho 229 used "drag rudders" at the tips of the wing to control yaw:

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://dodlithr.blogspot.com/2011/10/horten-ho-229-or-ix-construction.html)</sup>

These devices are in the family of airbrakes, they create drag, not to be confused with spoilers which destruct lift.

Comment: I think we can be confident that those drag rudders did in fact cause some reduction of lift when deployed.   (Unless of course the wings had so much washout that that region of the wing actually created *downward* lift-- unlikely.)  Not to say that you are wrong about the *primary purpose* for which they were designed, but...