# Does "nose dive" have a technical aviation meaning?

Tags: terminology

I've usually heard the term 'nose dive' used in a metaphorical sense -- "Wow, your stock portfolio is really in a nose dive!"

Does it have any legitimate aviation meaning?

More specifically, is it redundant?  Are there types of dives which do not involve a nose-down attitude?

Comment: I'd say 'nose dive' and 'tail spin' share two qualities: nonstandard terminology (for 'dive' and 'spin'), and invariably negative connotations, though either may be a deliberate manoeuvre.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there types of dives which do not involve a nose-down attitude?

Yes (although these are not always intentional): a [graveyard spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_spiral) can occur without a nose down attitude. You can also stall a plane nose high and begin diving to the ground maintaining a stalled nose high attitude, this is similar to what happened to [AirFrance 447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447). A [flat spin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/is-it-possible-to-recover-from-a-flat-spin) will also result in "falling" vertically with a relatively flat nose attitude.

In my experience "nose dive" and "dive" are generally interchangeable.

Comment: Maybe a matter of semantics, but I would not refer to a stalled nose high descent as a dive.  And I certainly wouldn't call it a nose dive either.  Dive implies going head first.  Think of jumping into a swimming pool vs diving.

Comment: "DIVE DIVE DIVE" makes me think that perhaps it was originally a submariner term, as it would make more sense in that context -- but that rather takes us out of the scope of this SE.

Comment: It does if the TCAS system is equipped with the klaxon horn option; AOOOOOGA   AOOOOOOOGA   DIVE...DIVE.. DIVE.   Make sure the conning tower hatch is closed though.

Comment: @Bianfable my head must have been elsewhere, I removed the TCAS reference as it is indeed incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have any legitimate aviation meaning?

Yes.  It appears occasionally in FAA [accident reports](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Afaa.gov+nosedive).

> Is it redundant?

In all of those appearances, yes, technically.  "Dive" would suffice.

No, as an (unintentional) rhetorical device.  The phrase often used here is some variation on "took a nose dive," which betrays the informality of the writer or the interviewee.